# Is $\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)\,dt$ continuous?

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity

So I was solving a question which asked me to tell whether the function $f (x)=\int_{0}^{x} t\sin (1/t) \,dt $ is continuous. The answer given is that the function **is** continuous.

I want to know the reason behind it. What I think that since the function $x \sin (1/x) $ is continuous, its area is also going to be a continuous and hence the function $f (x) $ is continuous. Is my reasoning correct? Is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: Yes, and you even can conlude, from First Fundamental theorem of Integral Calculus, that $f$ is differentiable, and its derivative is $f'(x)=x\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Applying the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition directly isn't really difficult.

Comment: You could give a slightly more formal proof using the Mean value theorem.

Comment: @Sobi could you please elaborate

Comment: You could study $\vert f(x+h)-f(x) \vert$ and show that it converges to 0 as $h\to 0$. But this might be an overkill, depending on your needs. As Bernard suggested, it is probably easiest to use the Fundamental theorem of Calculus directly.

Comment: Although, the theorem FToC requires you to have a function that is continuous (and in particular well-defined) on the *closed* interval [0, x]. The function $t \mapsto t \sin(1/t)$ is not well defined at 0, but it can be continuously extended there, so the theorem can be used. Again, arguing about this might be an overkill though.

Comment: If $f$ is integrable on $[a, b] $ then $F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ is continuous on $[a, b] $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, note that $$\big|f (x)-f(y)\big|=\\\bigg|\int_{0}^{x} t\sin (1/t) \,dt -\int_{0}^{y} t\sin (1/t) \,dt\bigg|\\=\bigg|\int_{x}^{y} t\sin (1/t) \,dt\bigg|\le \int _x^y|t\sin (1/t) |\,dt\\\le \int_{x}^{y} |t|\,dt=\frac {1}{2}|x^2-y^2|$$